# Redirecting based on value in database - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, sql-server-ce

My website is going to have just 1 registered user and she is going to tell the visitor where her boyfriend is. If he is in town, I would like to redirect visitors to the `InTown` action of the `HomeController`. The corresponding view would have a green background and lack the buttons that let you know where he is, etc.

So this one user can log in, and edit my only database entry - These things are already working. But I cannot get my `HomeController` to read from the database and check `InTown` value (true or false) of the item that has an Id of "1". Could you please help me?

I don't really have much to show you here, I only have two classes in models that lets me interact with SqlServerCE (I'm using Entity Framework), and the most basic stuff.

Comment: It's hard to tell why you are having trouble getting some code working without seeing what you already have.

Comment: What exactly should I post? I don't have anything because I cannot figure out how to get started with this part of my project. All I have in my HomeController is this:         public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult InTown()
        {
            return View();
        }

Comment: I want to be able to say, inside my Index action, if(InTown == "true" in the database entry with an id of 1) redirecttoaction(InTown);

Comment: Ah. So you don't even know how to connect to the database in the first place.  I guess it was misleading to me: `and edit my only database entry - These things are *already working*` :)

Comment: They are tho :). I have a Cagla.cs and a CaglaContext.cs and a CaglaController (Cagla is the name of the guy) that take care of those things, I tried doing the same thing I did in the CaglaController in my HomeController and I got intellisense for stuff like db.Caglas.Find(id). So, in short, yes, I think I am able to interact with my database. But yeah, I'm new, and I don't know how to do conditional stuff like this, if database says x do y.

Comment: Righto. So you're not sure how to turn that into the logic you said above?  Still not sure where you're having trouble.

Comment: If you are using entity framework, can't you just use a where clause, such as: 'db.Caglas.Where(c => c.ID == 1).SingleOrDefault();'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using entity framework, can't you just use a where clause, such as: `db.Caglas.Where(c => c.ID == 1).SingleOrDefault();`

This is just a simple LINQ statement

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you, that was helpful, but I still cant get to the InTown column, or should I study some more LINQ first?

Comment: Is the InTown column part of the Caglas table?

Comment: Yes it is, I only have one table.

Comment: Well if the Entity Framework is working properly, with the returned object from the LINQ query, you should be able to go: 'cagla.InTown'. You could also do this instead: 'db.Caglas.Where(c => c.ID == 1).Select(c => c.InTown).SingleOrDefault();'

Comment: The first one isn't working. Maybe I should post CaglaContext at this point, this is what I have in there:         public CaglaContext() : base("CaglaGeldiMi")
        { }

        public DbSet<Cagla> Caglas { get; set; }
    }

Comment: What is in the Cagla class? That is what needs to have the InTown public property. You will not be able to access it until that is included.

Comment: With the second one, this is gonna look ridiculous I'm sure, but I tried to use the returned value as this:             db.Caglas.Where(c => c.Id == 1).Select(c => c.InTown).FirstOrDefault();
            if (c == true)
            {
                RedirectToAction("InTown");
            }

Comment: if you are going to use the result, then you need to assign a variable to the method return like this: bool inTown = db.Caglas.Where(c => c.Id == 1).Select(c => c.InTown).FirstOrDefault(); ... then you could run your check, but once again InTown needs to be your Cagla class

Comment: public class Cagla
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public bool GeldiMi { get; set; }
        public string NeZamanGelcek { get; set; }
        public string Nerdeymis { get; set; }
    }

GeldiMi is the InTown one. I just type GeldiMi whenever you say InTown.

Comment: Ok, well you will only have access to what is in the Cagla class. And the column names are required to match the column names in the database in order for entity framework to work.

Comment: Ok, I'm not getting any errors, but I'm not getting redirected to the other view either (I should be because GeldiMi column shows True), this is what I have:

        private CaglaContext db = new CaglaContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            bool GeldiMi = db.Caglas.Where(c => c.Id == 1).Select(c => c.GeldiMi).FirstOrDefault();
            if (GeldiMi == true)
            {
                RedirectToAction("Geldi");
            }
                return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Geldi()
        {
            return View();
        }

Comment: Are you certain that your locally declared GeldiMi boolean is returning as true? The LINQ statement is a deffered query, meaning that it is not executed until it is needed (in the where clause). My guess is that is is false once the actual query is ran.

Comment: Oh, it works if I do a return View("Geldi") inside the if. I guess I should read up on redirecting to find what I was doing wrong there. Thank you for your time, it must be difficult dealing with a total beginner.

Comment: No problem at all. Would you consider up voting my answer and marking it as completed so I get some credit? In addition, you are probably not getting redirected because you are not returning your redirection. Your redirect line needs a return like this: 'return RedirectToAction("Geldi");'